# Resetting every button's text and enabled value using foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, button, foreach

I made a simple tic tac toe game in C# (Visual Studio Winform). I added a menu strip containing a file menu which has a "New Game" option in it. What i'm trying to do is to reset all the buttons' text and I had disabled them so I want to enable them again. I used the following code when I only had a menustrip and the buttons on my form, and it worked. But now I added a label to my form, and this code is not working. I know I can simply reset the value one by one for each button, but I wanted to know what went wrong when I added a label. Thanks in advance. :)

```
try
     {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
           Button b = (Button)c;
           b.Text = "";
           b.Enabled = true;
        }
     }
     catch { }
```

Comment: Swallows exception. Posts on StackOverflow to find out what the error is... Hopefully helpful tip: in Visual Studio under the Debug menu then Exceptions you can tell VS to break on an exception when thrown *even if handled/swallowed*. The same could be achieved by removing the try/catch even if just temporarily. Either would likely have revealed the cause of the bug and would be far more satisfying and educational than have someone else tell you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work anymore because the Controls collection now contains also the Label, so when your loop reaches the Label control it throws an exception at this line

```
 Button b = (Button)c;
```

You cannot cast a Label to be a Button, but this exception is swallowed by the empty try catch and your loop terminates without any warning.  It is considered a bad practice to have empty try/catch, better remove them and let the exception show.

Your problem could be avoided using the [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) enumerable extension to get only the controls of type Button. The rest of your code now doesn't need any other changes.

```
foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   b.Text = "";
   b.Enabled = true;
}
```

However keep in mind that this loop works on the Form Controls container. If you add some other kind of container (like a GroupBox or a Panel) and move your buttons inside that control then you need to loop on that container Controls property.

**EDIT**
To exclude a particular button from the loop you could add a call to [`IEnumerable<T>.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) to the sequence returned by `OfType`. For example

```
foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name != "button10")
.....
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! I was wondering if I wanted to select all the buttons except one, how would I do it? As in what would I change in "foreach (Button b in Controls.OfType<Button>())"? Lets say my button is "button10", and I dont want it to be edited in the foreach body.. Could you help me out please? Thanks

Comment: Answer updated assuming that you want to exclude a button whose name is "button10"

Answer (score 2):

```
 this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(b => { b.Text = ""; b.Enabled = true; });
```